# Mysql : JOIN two tables

Tags: mysql

I'm having two tables named as
1.)Primary_Table
2.)Secondary_Table

as shown below:-

```
Primary_Table                          Secondary_Table
Sl_no Sub_id  Destination              Sub_id   Price 
1       1000  New York                  1000    1987 
1       1001  Tokyo                     1001    5679 
1       1002  London                    1002    7875 
2       1003  Mumbai                    1003    6789 
2       1004  Sydney                    1004    7489 
2       1005  Munich                    1005    6746
```

Here I'm trying to write a SQL/MYSQL query to find the maximum and minimum price with respect to the Sl_no, which is in primary table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: you'll need to join the two tables, before using aggregate MIN/MAX functions on the data.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for as you have tagged both Oracle and MySQL?

Comment: I cannot join two rows and create a new table as I'm writing a procedure and I need a SQL query which will fetch the required data.

Comment: @Jhon where was it mentioned you'd need to create a table? Your first task would be to write a query that joins the two tables and provides output that you can then group on the min/max price per sl_no.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this solution.

```
SELECT
     tb1.sub_id
   , tb1.sl_no
   , tb1.destination 
   , tb2.price
FROM
  tb1
JOIN
  tb2
ON
  tb2.sub_id = tb1.sub_id
WHERE
  price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM tb2) OR price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM tb2)
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you max and min price for each `Sub_id`

```
SELECT Sub_id,MIN(Price) AS minimum, MAX(Price) AS maximum FROM 
(SELECT p.si,p.sub,s.price FROM Primary_Table as p JOIN  Secondary_Table as s ON  
p.Sub_id=s.Sub_id) AS t GROUP BY t.Sub_id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28dd5/8)

Comment: @Jhon Is it working for you?. if yes feel free to up vote and mark as correct